# How to set default database name when creating a cluster

Tags: postgresql

When creating a cluster using `initdb`

```
$ initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

it creates a default database user `postgres` and database name `postgres`.

I need to create a cluster with a different superuser name and default database name. I found the way to have a different name for superuser:

```
$ initdb --username=myuser
```

But can't find how to define the different name for the database instead of `postgres`. How can I do that? Is my only option is to rename the default DB after it's been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the database "postgres" is hardcoded in the initdb-code. You could build your own version of initdb and use a different name for this specific database or you run a script afterwards that renames this database.

Comment: thanks for the clarification! I start the DB from a docker `posgres` image. So I have 2 options now:  use variable `POSTGRES_DB` and the script will create an extra database that will be set as default and after that I run my own script to remove `posgres` hardcoded db. And 2nd option is to not use `POSTGRES_DB`, but rather run my own script after initialization to rename `postgres` to whatever name I'd pass through `POSTGRES_DB`. Second option seems to be better. What do you suggest?

Comment: I would just rename the default postgres database. Very simple solution that always works.

Comment: a quick clarification, it seems I still need to connect to any other database to be able to rename the default one, so does it mean I'll still need to create an extra database?

Comment: No, you can connect to template0 or template1, the two templates that are always there.